# How to update multiple rows with diffrent data?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using code to import data from excel sheet, it's work fine when I import the sheet for the first time it's insert the values to mysql, but when I change some values on the sheet and try to import the data, it's not update any thing.

```
$query = "SELECT positionid FROM vacant WHERE positionid = '".$position."' and ptitle = '".$ptitle."' and location = '".$location."' and vacantd = '".$vdate."' and candidate = '".$resultcandidate."' and cv = '".$cvtorsaf."'";
$sql = mysql_query($query);

if (!$sql) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
$recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql);


$existName = $recResult["positionid"];
if($existName=="") {
$insertTable= mysql_query("insert into vacant (positionid, ptitle, location, vacantd, candidate, cv) values('".$position."', '".$ptitle."', '".$location."', '".$vdate."', '".$resultcandidate."', '".$cvtorsaf."');");


$msg = 'Record has been added. <div style="Padding:20px 0 0 0;"><a href="">Go Back to tutorial</a></div>';
} else {

mysql_query("UPDATE vacant SET ptitle = '".$ptitle."', location = '".$location."', vacantd = '".$vdate."', candidate = '".$resultcandidate."', cv = '".$cvtorsaf."' WHERE positionid IN '".$position."'");

$msg = 'Record already exist. <div style="Padding:20px 0 0 0;"><a href="">Go Back to tutorial</a></div>';

}
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead and learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: If it works the first time but not for any subsequent queries, check for errors then; you're not doing that.